# error in restored MySql files in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Disk crashed.  The folder containing MySql database was recovered and placed on an external drive.  I installed MySql on a new machine, and moved the recovered folder to var/lib/mysql.  Show tables lists all the tables.  About 1/2 of them are fine.  The other half give the error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'Moxware.AuxXref' doesn't exist
```

(where AuxXref is the table name).

Looking at the actual Moxware folder I find that some of the tables do have .frm .MYD and .MYI files, but the tables that are returning errors do not have the .MYD and .MYI files.

My question is: is there any hope of restoring the erroneous tables, given that the MYD and MYI files are not there?  (I suspect not, but would like that confirmed).

If that cannot be done, do the .FRM files contain the table definitions?  And if so, is there a way I could see those? (which would help greatly in rebuilding this database).

I am in Ubuntu 14.04 and MySql 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and it turns out you can indeed recover the table definition from the .frm file.  I refer you to this website which explains how to do it. http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/02/recover-table-structure-frm-files-mysql-utilities/

Since the explanation is not quite complete, or doesn't quite fit with my installation, I'll add these comments.

First, the mysqlfrm utility runs from the terminal, not inside MySql.  Second to use the msqlfrm utility you have to have the MySql utilities installed.  When I simply typed the mysqlfrm command, I got instructions on how to install this with an apt-get,and it works very well.  Third, the create statement that is generated is again outside of MySql.  It will tell you how to reconstruct your file, but does not actually do so.

Since I was missing the MYD and MYI files, I used drop table from inside MySQl to get rid of the bad .frm file.  This both generated an error that the file does not exist, and also dropped the .frm file.  I then recreated my table structure from the create generated by mysqlfrm.